# Different variables per user

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am using a local agent hosted on my own computer. In case I want more people to work on the same project, is there a way to have a variable that is different for every user?

In my case, I have in mind passwords for API calls that need to be unique for every user when each one  tries to run a pipeline.

Comment: Are the API calls to a Azure-DevOps endpoint?  Or to some external endpoint?

Comment: @Matt they are calls to an external endpoint created by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you may be able leverage the build in variable Build.QueuedBy, which is the user who kicked off the build

You can also define additional variables for passwords, keyed by user(no space):

user1: password1
user2: password2

and use powershell you can dynamically retrieve the password:

$password = '$env:'+"$(build.QueuedBy)".replace(" ","")| Invoke-Expression

Comment: This seems interesting, but does this mean that the passwords have to be located on the local agent and be visible by all?

Comment: no in Azure Devops you can make variable secret and it will be stay hidden throughout the process.

Comment: drop a powershell task. CmdLine@2 won't work

Comment: A note on this: The answer is correct but keep in mind that anyone can view and edit a secret variable while editing a pipeline. Maybe Azure Key Vault can offer some additional functionality.